# Redis specific protocol

Tags: tcp, redis

I was reading the redis documentation:

http://redis.io/topics/quickstart

And I come across this line

"External programs talk to Redis using a TCP socket and a Redis specific protocol."

TCP is the actual protocol it says it is using to talk to clients. So then what does it mean redis specific protocol? TCP is not redis specific at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is just the L3 protocol, redis will be referring to higher-tier protocols it uses, simple as that.

Comment: And what are these higher-tier protocols?

Comment: This is really basic stuff; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model